# Languages to develop games

Tags: game-design, education

Hello I am a 10th grade student from India...I have been playing games since a very young age. I want to work in the game industry as a game developer...I have started learning the basics of C programming language...Can anyone tell me which language I should focus on or should I just continue with C

Thank You

Comment: Along with programming, also learn math and physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's great that you want to get into game development. When it comes to choosing a programming languages, it all boils down to your requirements.

Some examples:

- If you want to develop for Android, take a look at Java.
- If you want to develop for Xbox 360 or Windows Phone take a look at
  C#.

There are some choices that will work great on several platforms. C or C++ are some of them. Learning C is a good choice, but I would not actually recommend it. Game development is not really about the language, it's more about abstract concepts and patterns, most languages support an implementation of these. So it does not really matter which languages you choose.

I would recommend C++ or C#, to ease the learning curve. Remember there's much more to learn then just the language when it comes to game development. One important thing to remember is that making games is nothing like playing them.

Comment: Thank you willhelm...I think I'll go with c++ for now :-)